# Counting in a sql query

Tags: sql, visual-studio, datagridview

So I'm having a table like

[image]

Now I need to get this packed into a datagridview when a choice is made in a combobox filled with the  uv ='owner'. 
If I make a choice of the uv eg MG. I get a list of all his files/dosno he worked in and the times he spend working on the file.

I do this with this query :

```
SELECT kbpres.uv, 
       dbo.doss.dosno, 
       SUM(dbo.kbpres.uur) AS somuur, 
       SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut) AS somminuut, 
       CAST (( SUM(dbo.kbpres.uur) + SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut) / 60 ) AS VARCHAR(4) 
       ) + 
       'u ' + CAST (( SUM(dbo.kbpres.minuut) % 60 ) AS VARCHAR(2)) + 'm' AS 
       [derivedColumn], 
       doss.behdr 
FROM   dbo.kbpres 
       INNER JOIN dbo.doss 
         ON dbo.kbpres.ino = dbo.doss.ino 
WHERE  ( dbo.kbpres.uv LIKE @cboBeheerder ) 
GROUP  BY kbpres.uv, 
          dbo.doss.dosno, 
          doss.behdr
```

(Allthough I would only like to group by UV, and have to add the dosno and behdr as well ??)

The problem is now, how can I count the correct cost, as it is per record different.
for MG it would be :

10 * 60 for dosno 88888

20 * 76 for 66666

60*10 + (28hours+10minutes * 10) + 10*2  for 12345

Any idea if this is even possible ??

Comment: Please, paste the data as data, not a picture...

Comment: Aye, I can't see the pictures from work :(

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT dosno,
  SUM(uur)*60 + SUM(minuut) AS Time,
  (SUM(uur)*60 + SUM(minuut)) * cost AS TotalCost
FROM dbo.kbpres k
INNER JOIN dbo.doss d ON k.ino = d.ino 
GROUP BY dosno,k.ino,d.ino,cost
WHERE k.uv = 2
```

---

As cost seems to be a function of uv and dosno try

```
SELECT dosno,SUM(Time) AS Time,SUM(TotalCost) AS TotalCost FROM
(
SELECT dosno,
  uur*60 + minuut AS Time,
  (uur*60 + minuut) * cost AS TotalCost
FROM dbo.kbpres k
INNER JOIN dbo.doss d ON k.ino = d.ino 
GROUP BY dosno,k.ino,d.ino,cost
WHERE k.uv = 2
) t
GROUP BY dosno
```

Comment: with me it says cost should be in an aggregate or a group by. Is that really necessary or is my query not correctly build ?

Comment: Group by cost also. I have made the assumption that cost is a value per minute and so am simply showing how you can both add and multiply aggregate values - the SUM(...) values... to get the result you are looking for.

Comment: I had also thought that cost was the same for each uv with each dosno when in fact it is different. I will update accordingly.

Comment: I tried this but I always got an error so I tried only the inner select and it only works when I add the uur and minuut into the groupby as well, but then I have eg 26 rows instead of justy one :

SELECT     d.dosno, k.uur * 60 + k.minuut AS Time, (k.uur * 60 + k.minuut) * k.prijs AS TotalCost
FROM         dbo.kbpres AS k INNER JOIN
                      dbo.doss AS d ON k.ino = d.ino
WHERE     (d.dosno = '93690')
GROUP BY d.dosno, k.ino, d.ino, k.prijs, k.uur, k.minuut